# Prefer heap over stack?

Tags: c++, class, object

I recently dove into graphics programming and I noticed that many graphic engines (i.e Ogre), and many coders overall, prefer to initialize class instances dynamically. Here's an example from [Ogre Basic Tutorial 1](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Basic%20Tutorial%201)

```
//...

Ogre::Entity* ogreHead = mSceneMgr->createEntity("Head", "ogrehead.mesh");
Ogre::SceneNode* headNode = mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode("HeadNode");

//...
```

`ogreHead` and `headNode` data members and methods are then referred to as `ogreHead->blabla`.

Why mess around with object pointers instead of plain objects?

BTW, I've also read somewhere that heap memory allocation is much slower than stack memory allocation.

Comment: Note that many libraries often have a pool of pre-allocated objects (therefore called "object pools") so their `new` calls are much faster than the provided `new`.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by "pool of pre-allocated objects"?

Comment: An object pool is basically "I'm going to `new` 50 objects of `Foo` right off the bat. When someone calls `new` I'll just re-initialize one of these and let them use it. When they `delete` I'll just take the object back for reuse." This saves on the constructor and destructor overhead time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

Comment: Why is this the preferred approach? How do the engine designers know how much of those pool objects the coder is going to attempt to use?

Comment: Because (in the example you give) the `ogreHead` entity need to live for longed than the stack frame in which it is created.  it's probably created deep inside nested calls to create a scene which needs to live longer than just the scene creation function.

Comment: @Pilpel they instrument the pool code and try it and see.

Comment: Returning dynamically allocated pointers from factory functions is also necessary if the return type is polymorphic.  Modern code should prefer to return a smart pointer, however.

Comment: What do you mean by "the return type is polymorphic"? I know what polymorphism is but I don't get your statement.

Comment: @Pilpel Basically it means, you should take care of ownership for heap allocated objects (no matter, if _polymorphic_ or not).

Comment: "Returning a polymorphic object" means that you are returning an object that was created based on some inputs, e.g. `shape1 = createShape("Triangle"); shape2 = createShape("Square");` would create two different object of different classes, although they are the same basetype. No matter what you do, if your what you are returning can be more than one thing, it (almost always) needs to be allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heap allocation is, inevitably much slower than stack allocation. More on "How much slower?" later. However, in many cases, the choice is "made for you", for several reasons:

1. Stack is limited. And if you run out, the application almost always gets terminated - there is no real good recovery, even printing an error message to say "I ran out of stack" may be hard...
2. Stack allocation "goes away" when you leave the function where the allocation was made.
3. Variability is much more well defined and easy to deal with. C++ does not cope with "variable length arrays" very well, and it's certainly not guaranteed to work in all compilers.

How much slower is heap over stack?

We'll get to "and does it matter" in a bit.

For a given allocation, stack allocation is simply a subtract operation [1], where at the very minimum `new` or `malloc` will be a function call, and probably even the most simple allocator will be several dozen instructions, in complex cases thousands [because memory has to be gotten from the OS, and cleared of it's previous content]. So anything from a 10x to "infinitely" slower, give or take. Exact numbers will depend on the exact system the code is running in, size of the allocation, and often "previous calls to the allocator" (e.g. a long list of "freed" allocations can make allocating a new object slower, because a good fit has to be searched for). And of course, unless you do the "ostrich" method of heap management, you also need to free the object and cope with "out of memory" which adds more code/time to the execution and complexity of the code.

With some reasonably clever programming, however, this can be mostly hidden - for example, allocating something that stays allocated for a long time, over the lifetime of the object, will be "nothing to worry about". Allocating objects from the heap for every pixel or every trianle in a 3D game would CLEARLY be a bad idea. But if the lifetime of the object is many frames or even the entire game, the time to allocate and free it will be nearly nothing.

Similarly, instead of doing 10000 individual object allocations, make one for 10000 objects. Object pool is one such concept.

Further, often the allocation time isn't where the time is spent. For example, reading a triangle list from a file from a disk will take much longer than allocating the space for the same triangle list - even if you allocate each single one!

To me, the rule is:

1. Does it fit nicely on the stack? Typically a few kilobytes is fine, many kilobytes not so good, and megabytes definitely not ok.
2. Is the number (e.g. array of objects) known, and the maximum such that you can fit it on the stack?
3. Do you know what the object will be? In other words abstract/polymorphic classes will probably need to be allocated on the heap.
4. Is its lifetime the same as the scope it is in? If not, use the heap (or stack further down, and pass it up the stack).

[1] Or add if stack is "grows towards high addresses" - I don't know of a machine which has such an architecture, but it is conceivable and I think some have been made. C certainly makes no promises as to which way the stack grows, or anything else about how the runtime stack works.

Comment: One more c++ question. Is it needed for me to design the classes to be allocated on the heap? What I mean is should I write my classes differently if I know that I'm going to create instances of them on the heap?

Comment: I typically don't. I expect my classes to be created "either on stack or on heap" [in general, of course some cases you "know" that they will be created some special way, but the method of creation doesn't change how the object is designed - that is about "what problem am I trying to solve, and how do we solve that"]

Comment: A question that just came to my mind. Why have a pool and not let the programmer decide exactly how many object he wants to have, instead of encapsulating a number of pre-allocated instances inside a class? Isn't he smart enough to know that he can allocate data for all the objects he wants or may want at the beginning of his code?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on the circumstance. Say you are writing a compiler, and want to create variable-object (that holds name, such as "a" and type, such as "int"). Now, when you write the compiler, you don't know how many variables you need, right (it depends on the source code you are compiling)? But you probably know that you need a few, so having a pool of variables would help....

Comment: I get it, although it seems like having a pool is only good for rather odd cases...

Comment: Yes, it's typically only useful for special cases where you don't know "beforehand" how many you need of something, but you know you need "a few". As always with performance and behaviour, run a profiler to analyse where the time is spent. Otherwise the risk is that you spend time on tweaking something that takes 1% of the execution time, when there's something that can be easily changed that takes 60%.

Answer (score 4):

The scope of the stack is limited: it only exists within a function.  Now, modern user-interfacing programs are usually event driven, which means that a function of yours is invoked to handle an event, and then that function must return in order for the program to continue running.  So, if your event handler function wishes to create an object which will remain in existence after the function has returned, clearly, that object cannot be allocated on the stack of that function, because it will cease to exist as soon as the function returns. That's the main reason why we allocate things on the heap.

There are other reasons, too.

Sometimes, the exact size of a class is not known during compilation time.  If the exact size of a class is not known, it cannot be created on the stack, because the compiler needs to have precise knowledge of how much space it needs to allocate for each item on the stack.

Furthermore, factory methods like `whatever::createEntity()` are often used. If you have to invoke a separate method to create an object for you, then that object cannot be created on the stack, for the reason explained in the first paragraph of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why pointers instead of objects?

Because pointers help make things fast. If you pass an object by value, to another function, for example

```
shoot(Orge::Entity ogre)
```

instead of

```
shoot(Orge::Entity* ogrePtr)
```

If ogre isn't a pointer, what happens is you are passing the whole object into the function, rather than a reference. If the compiler doesn't optimize, you are left with an inefficient program. There are other reasons too, with the pointer, you can modify the passed in object (some argue references are better but that's a different discussion). Otherwise you would be spending too much time copying modified objects back and forth.

Why heap?

1. In some sense heap is a safer type of memory to access and allows you to safely reset/recover. If you call new and don't have memory, you can flag that as an error. If you are using the stack, there is actually no good way to know you have caused stackoverflow, without some other supervising program, at which point you are already in danger zone.
2. Depends on your application. Stack has local scope so if the object goes out of scope, it will deallocate memory for the object. If you need the object in some other function, then no real way to do that.
3. Applies more to OS, heap is comparatively much larger than stack, especially in multi-threaded application where each thread can have a limited stack size.

Comment: I think you might be meandering a bit in this answer.  For example, if you are passing a pointer, you are by definition "passing by reference", which you seem to differentiate as something different in your answer.  Also, comments about the safety of the heap versus the stack are questionable.  It is equally easy to inadvertently overwrite memory pointers on the heap.  In fact, in some ways the stack is safer.  While any overflow condition that we permit in our code is extremely serious, at least when the stack unwinds (provided we haven't overwritten the frame) we can return to a good state.

Comment: Fair point about stack can be safer but my point was not corruption of stack or heap by something else. It was more that heap allows you to know if you have enough memory to allocate (by checking the return of new) while this is not the same in stack.

Note about reference is that in c++ references can't be null and have to point to an object, but pointers can be null.